# Get 3D coordinated from 2D coordinates

Tags: opencv, image-processing

My object is to calculate the 3D (world) coordinates from the 2D (image) coordinates. For this, using a chessboard I've calculated the intrinsic (for camera) and extrinsic (for a particular image) matrix. Let's suppose that I've saved the camera matrix in `mtx` and distortion coefficients in `dist`. Also, the size of an individual square of the chessboard id `25` mm for a 9x6 board. I've used `solvePnP` to get the extrinsic matrix:

```
sq_size = 25
rows = 9
cols = 6

objp = np.zeros((cols * rows,3), np.float32)
objp[:,:2] = np.mgrid[0:rows,0:cols].T.reshape(-1,2)
objp = objp*sq_size

retval,myRvec,myTvec=cv2.solvePnP(objectPoints=objp, 
                                  imagePoints=corners.reshape(-1, 2), 
                                  cameraMatrix=mtx, 
                                  distCoeffs=dist)
```

Using the `myRvec` and `myTvec` I can convert the world coordinate to the image coordinate like this:

```
axis = np.float32([[1,0,0], [0,1,0], [0,0,-1]]).reshape(-1,3)*sq_size
imgpts, jac = cv2.projectPoints(axis, myRvec, myTvec, mtx, dist)
```

Now I want to reverse the process; given the image coordinate I want to calculate the world coordinate, how to do that ?

**Edit**
I've found Homography using following:

```
pts_dst = np.zeros((cols * rows,2), np.float32)
pts_dst[:,:2] = np.mgrid[0:rows,0:cols].T.reshape(-1,2)
pts_dst = pts_dst*sq_size

pts_src, jac = cv2.projectPoints(objp, myRvec, myTvec, mtx, dist)
pts_src = np.squeeze(pts_src)

h, status = cv2.findHomography(pts_src, pts_dst)
transformed = np.zeros((img.shape[0], img.shape[1]), dtype=np.uint8);
dst = cv2.warpPerspective(img, h, transformed.shape)
```

And here is my output:
[image]

Why am I missing th right side of the chessboard and how to correct it ?

Comment: solvePnp already gives you the object pose

Comment: @Micka Yes, solvePnP already gave me the pose, but I ned to know the function which can transform image coordinates to world coordinates.

Comment: this isnt possible. If you know the object pose and object geometry (e.g. 3d mesh), you can create a ray from the camera center through the pixel and compute the 3d point where ray hits the object.

Comment: @Micka how to do that ?

Comment: convert image plane to 3D plane (with information about the pixel size in real size from your intrinsics), then calucalte the direction vector from (0,0) to the pixel. Then formulate the mathematical ray according to that direction. Then compute the intersection points with all the triangles from the object 3D mesh. Then sort, which one was the first hit. If your object is a pure or approximated plane (like a chessboard), you could use homographies instead, which makes things much easier.

Comment: @Micka my object of interest (a plane) and chessboard are on the same plane. Can you share an example, how to use  `homographies` in my case ?

Comment: from a coarse view it looks like https://zbigatron.com/mapping-camera-coordinates-to-a-2d-floor-plan/ covers what you need

Comment: @Micka I've added  homographies, and updated my question, but I'm not able to get the right side of the chessboard.